# WPF application will not close if Visual Studio is installed

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio, process

I develop a WPF application that closes by calling Application.Current.Shutdown. When installed on a 'normal' machine, and the app is closed all the windows close and the process exits just fine. But, when installed on a machine with Visual Studio, the windows close on shutdown but the process never exits.

How might one go about tracking down why the process is not exiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved itself with new updates to Visual Studio, and without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may help, [microsoft application shutdown.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)

Do you have the XAML also containing the shutdown like on here?

Read the 4th paragraph down in the 'remarks' section.

Comment: As stated in the first sentence of my question, I'm already calling Application.Shutdown

Comment: Does both your program code and xaml contain it like shown in the link i have given?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: The way I understand the docs is that the wpf framework will automatically call shutdown for you if certain conditions are met according to ShutdownMode. If Shutdown is being called explicitly, then the shutdown should happen either when the ShutdownMode conditions are met, or when Shutdown is called explicitly by the application code. Just to be thorough though, I have set ShutdownMode to OnExplicitShutdown (but in C#, not Xaml because we explicitly instantiate our own Application).